# App crashes when using null data returned in JSON

Tags: ios, json

```
{
   "prodid":"32",
   "prodname":"Casserole Stainless steel",
   "imageurl":"bimg51590b400f339.jpg"
},
{
   "prodid":"783",
   "prodname":   **null**
   "imageurl":"simg51b02ba3a9dcd.jpg"
},
{
   "prodid":"641",
   "prodname":"EVAPORATIVE COOLING DOG PAD",
   "imageurl":"simg5184dd5b21d0b.jpg"
}

 if ([response count]>0) {
    for (NSUInteger i =0; i < [response count]; i++) {
        self.workingEntry = [[AppRecord alloc]init];
        self.workingEntry.ID = [[response objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"prodid"];
        NSString * name = [[[response objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"prodname"]retain];
        self.workingEntry.name = name;
```

The crash occurs when the "prodname" field is null. How do I stop this?

Comment: I don't see a question here?

Comment: my app is crashed at the response of product name is null

Comment: try it - (id)objectOrNilForKey:(id)aKey fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    id object = [dict objectForKey:aKey];
    return [object isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? nil : object;
}  

Pass key and one object as dictionary.

Comment: not working. again the same issue

Comment: can you edit your post by adding a question and checking the syntax of your code? so we can help you...

Comment: syntax is fine all the products are displaying except the product name= null.

Comment: yous just need to update your server's script to post empty string (`""`) instead of `null`.

Comment: {
   "prodid":"783",
   "prodname":   **null**"imageurl":"simg51b02ba3a9dcd.jpg"
} crash happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if ([response count]>0) {
    for (NSUInteger i =0; i < [response count]; i++) {
        self.workingEntry = [[AppRecord alloc]init];
        self.workingEntry.ID = [[response objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"prodid"];
      if(![[[response objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"prodname"] isEqual:[NSNull null]])
      {
        NSString * name = [[response objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"prodname"];
       }
     else
     {
      NSSTring *name = @"";
     }

        self.workingEntry.name = name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: i need to delete that entire cell or row

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop before assigning values

```
for(NSDictionary *product in response) {
    for(id key in [product allKeys]) {
        if([product valueForKey:key] == (id)[NSNull null]) {
            [product setValue:@"" forKey:key];

            //If you want to delete that null object
            //[response removeObject:product]
        }
    }
}
```

It'll remove all Null  objects with @"" empty `NSString`, so it won't crash when you assigned or use.

Comment: i need to delete that entire cell or row

Comment: Yes, you can delete that object too, instead of setting @"" line, just write this, `[response removeObject:product];` and it'll remove from your response array (Make sure array should be of type `NSMutableArray`).

Comment: if (name==(id) [NSNull null] || [name length]==0 || [name isEqualToString:@""]) {
            }  so what can i write here

Comment: If product_name will be `Null` then you can't check `length` or `isEqualToString` directly, first you should always check of `Null`. Check updated answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Nulls in JSON are converted to NSNull instances in arrays and dictionaries by NSJSONSerialization. This can cause problems when you start treating them like strings or numbers.

I made [this category](https://github.com/jrturton/NSJSONSerialization-NSNullRemoval) for removing them during serialisation, or post-serialisation recursively from dictionaries or arrays. It's available via Cocapods.